# Many-To-Many Entity Framework Update

Tags: linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have an object that has a many-to-many relationship with another object. I am trying to write an update statement that doesn't result in having to delete all records from the many-to-many table first.

My data is: 
StoredProcedure - StoredProcedureId, Name
Parameter - ParameterId, Name
StoredProcedure_Parameter - StoredProcedureId, ParameterId, Order

I have a UI for updating a stored procedured object (adding/removing parameters or changing the order of the parameters).

When I save, I end up at:

```
            var storedProcedure = context.Sprocs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SprocID == sproc.StoredProcedureId);
            if (storedProcedure == null)
            {
                //do something like throw an exception
            } else
            {
                storedProcedure.Name = sproc.Name;
                //resolve Parameters many to many here
                //remove all Params that are not in sproc.Params
                //Add any params that are in sproc.Params but not in storedProcedure.Params
                //Update the Order number for any that are in both

            }
```

I know I could simply call .Clear() on the table and then reinsert all of the values with their current state (ensuring that all parameters that were removed by the UI are gone, new ones are added, and updated Orders are changed). However, I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Do many-to-many updates with EF usually get resolved by deleting all of the elements and reinserting them?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is my code that I use and it works. The difference is that instead o having your 3 tables( StoredProcedure, StoredProcedure_Parameter and Parameter ) I have the following 3 tables: Order, OrdersItem(this ensure the many-to-many relation) and Item. This is the procedure that I used for updating or add an order, or after I change an existing OrderItem or add a new one to the Order.

```
    public void AddUpdateOrder(Order order)
    {
        using (var db = new vitalEntities())
        {
            if (order.OrderId == 0)
            {
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var orderItem in order.OrdersItems)
                {
                    if (orderItem.OrderItemsId == 0)
                    {
                        orderItem.Item = null;

                        if (order.OrderId != 0)
                            orderItem.OrderId = order.OrderId;

                        db.Entry(orderItem).State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderItem.Order = null;
                        orderItem.Item = null;

                        db.OrdersItems.Attach(orderItem);

                        db.Entry(orderItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }

                db.Orders.Attach(order);
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }


            SaveChanges(db);
        }
    }
```